# Reload page whenever change anything in code

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I write docker-compose.yaml like this.

```
node_app:
        container_name: my_node
        image: node:18.18.0-alpine
        restart: always
        working_dir: /home/node/mvc_node_express
        volumes:
          - ./:/home/node/mvc_node_express
        command: sh -c "npm install -g nodemon && npm install && npm run dev"
        environment:
          - NODE_ENV=production
        ports:
          - "3000:3000"
```

In package.json:

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "node src/index.js",
    "dev": "nodemon src/index.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
```

I want to reload the page whenever I edit something in index.js but it didn't work. How can I modify it?

Comment: Run `npm run dev` on your host system.  You don't need Docker for this use case, and since a core design point is that a container can't normally see files on the host, it can be inconvenient to hide your core development tools inside a container.

Comment: @DavidMaze But I want to try running it with docker to build microservices in the future. Anw, Thank you because your comment

Comment: You can develop using host tools and then eventually deploy your application using Docker, that works fine.  In a microservice setup it would work to run dependency services in containers while you're using host `npm` to develop and debug the one you're currently working on.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help you:

Add nodemon configuration to your project explicitly

***nodemon.json***

```
{
  "watch": ["/home/node/mvc_node_express/src"],
  "ext": "js,json"
}
```

***Dockerfile***

```
FROM node:18.18.0-alpine

WORKDIR /home/node/mvc_node_express

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["sh", "-c", "npm i -g nodemon && npm run dev"]
```

***docker-compose.yml***

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  node_app:
    container_name: my_node
    build:
      context: .
    restart: always
    working_dir: /home/node/mvc_node_express
    volumes:
      - ./:/home/node/mvc_node_express
    command: sh -c "npm i -g nodemon && npm i && npm run dev"
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=production
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

Comment: Thank you but it didn't work

Comment: @DanLeo I have updated my answer. Could you please recheck?

Comment: It didn't work. Thank you. Maybe I will run by npm to check.